# Windows 7 fails to finalise installation, black screen but mouse works

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I had Vista installed and have now tried to put Windows 7 on the machine. Setup completes but Windows fails to initialise. It goes to a black screen and then stays like that.

Safe mode loads but then restarts itself as it cannot complete the installation in safe mode.

The mouse cursor is visible. I've done this twice now…

Comment: Could you please check your system about any bios update? Did you use another installation media?

Comment: Hi yes will do thaie i think it might be bios relatd, was overclocked before too...dont know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes will look at the bios i think it is bios related...

Comment: Could the answers here (http://superuser.com/questions/947254/black-screen-while-installing-windows-10/947267) possibly also help you? Strikes me what you are experiencing with Win7 is very similar to those Win10 issues ...